# Symfony 4 LDAP Authentication and Roles loaded from local database

Tags: symfony, ldap

I am having trouble finding any help, examples or tutorials that layout how to use LDAP for Authorization but load the roles from a local database in Symfony 4.

Symfony documentation mentions that it can be done but does not illustrate how to do it. I have successfully authenticated with LDAP, I have also successfully authenticated with local database (Entity) and have even chained them so that one fails over to the other. This is not what I need.

What I need is to hook into the LDAP process so that after the LDAP server is successfully queried I can then query a local database to load the roles for the user to complete the authentication process.

Anyone have any experience with this?